# List(Of T) Sorting by a T property

Tags: vb.net, list, sorting

Can't wrap my head around this one but heres the scenario

2 Simple sample class:

```
Public Class Person
Public Name As String
Public Age as Integer
Public Last_Contact As New List(Of ContactInfo)
End Class

Public Class ContactInfo
Public Contact_Date As Date
Public Convo as String
End Class
```

in the Sub:

```
Dim myPersonList as New List(Of Person)
```

Now i know hot to sort myPersonList by first name and by age by simply doing the following:

```
myPersonList.Sort(Function (x,y) x.name.CompareTo(y.name))
```

How do I sort myPerson list by the order of the Last_Contact.ContactDate which is an already sorted list

So basically say in myPersonList I have

{Dave, 32, {02/22/2021, "Sample Convo"}, {01/12/2021 "Sample Convo"}}, John, 34 {04/08/2020, "sample convo"}}

How can I sort it so that the first item would be John would be the first item since the last contact date is the latest?

Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense that you have a class named `Last_Contact` but then, in the `Person` class, you have a field named `Last_Contact` of type `ContactInfo`.

Comment: Hang on! Are you trying to say that the `Person` class contains a collection of another class or just a single instance of it? The code you posted indicates the latter but some of the language used suggests the former. Please provide a FULL, CLEAR and ACCURATE explanation of the problem.

Comment: Sorry i wrote it wrong... fixed  But yes you are correct,  Last_Contact is also a collection.

Comment: I have three suggestions with regards to your code, unrelated to the question. 1) Don't use underscores in identifiers when words are already delimited by upper-case letters. 2) Use public properties rather than fields. 3) For variables and other identifiers that refer to arrays or collections, use plural names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to order the `Person` items by their most recent `Contact_Date` value. In that case, you need to get a `Max` value from the `Last_Contact` collection of each `Person` and compare those:

```vb
Dim people As New List(Of Person)

'...

people.Sort(Function(p1, p2) p2.Last_Contact.Max(Function(ci) ci.Contact_Date).CompareTo(p1.Last_Contact.Max(Function(ci) ci.Contact_Date)))
```

Note that I have reversed the order of `p1` and `p2` in the comparison. That is because the default sort order is ascending so, if you want descending, you need to reverse the order of the items when comparing.

It's worth noting that this code will enumerate the `Last_Contact` collections of both items each time a comparison is made. If the amount of data is small then that's no big deal but if there's a lot of data then that might make the whole process take a significant amount of time. Here's a more verbose alternative that will save time for large data sets:

```vb
Dim people As New List(Of Person)

'...

Dim items = people.ToArray()
Dim keys = Array.ConvertAll(items, Function(p) p.Last_Contact.Max(Function(ci) ci.Contact_Date))

Array.Sort(keys, items)

people.Clear()
people.AddRange(items)
```

This takes advantage of the existing array functionality that will sort an array of items based on another array of key values. There's overhead involved in this method, because you're creating arrays and then clearing and repopulating the collection. As such, it would likely be less efficient for small data sets but would certainly be more efficient for larger data sets.

Comment: @StavrosPehlivanidis, the answer has been updated.